# Bootstrap 3.1.1 navbar collapse button is not positioned correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using [Bootstrap v 3.1.1](http://getbootstrap.com/) and have customised the state at which I want the [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) to collapse using the [customisation page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) provided for Bootstrap.

However I am having issues where the collapsed button is not positioned correctly until I shrink the page to below tablet screen size.

[image: Screenshot of positioning issue with collapse button]

I have customised the `@grid-float-breakpoint` less variable to `@screen-md-min` which does cause the navbar to collapse at the correct screen size, but until I shrink the window passed tablet screen size (`@screen-sm-min`) the button has positioning problems.

[image: Less customisation showing collapse break point]

Am I missing a further variable customisation?

Comment: Do you have a code example, using JSFiddle or codepen.io etc?

Answer (score 1):

After investigating this a little I figured out that the css customisation was fine, it was the fact that I had wrapped my navbar in a div using the `class="container"` to centre it, but had also used the same class within the navbar...

```
<div class="container"> <!-- <<< wrapping container div -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container"> <!-- <<< root cause of positioning issue -->
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
```

The fix was simple, I just changed the div inside the navbar to use `class="container-fluid"` instead, which allowed it to correctly fit to the wrapping divs width...

```
<div class="container"> <!-- <<< wrapping container div -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid"> <!-- <<< here is the fix -->
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
```

Check [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremybrooks/EL9gt/) for the full fixed example.